# problems when making csv from array through regexp

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have an array from which I want to make a csv file.
Structure of the array:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(4) { 
        ["client_id"]=> "1234567" 
        ["name"]=> "nameOne" 
        ["messages_data"]=> array(5) { 
            ["2014-07-01"]=> int(0) 
            ["2014-07-02"]=> int(0) 
            ["2014-07-03"]=> int(0) 
            ["2014-07-04"]=> int(0) 
            ["2014-07-05"]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["account_manager"]=> "manager1" 
    }
    [1]=> array(4) { 
        ["client_id"]=> "1234568" 
        ["name"]=> "nameTwo" 
        ["messages_data"]=> array(5) { 
            ["2014-07-01"]=> int(53697) 
            ["2014-07-02"]=> int(57626) 
            ["2014-07-03"]=> int(55156) 
            ["2014-07-04"]=> int(50427) 
            ["2014-07-05"]=> int(44312)
        } 
        ["account_manager"]=> "manager2" 
    }
}
```

This is my csv file:

```
"Client id";"Client name";"Account manager";<!--DATES-->{{date}};<!--/DATES-->
<!--DATA1-->{{client_id}};{{name}};{{account_manager}};
<!--/DATA1-->
```

CVS file is filled through a "black box" php method. 
All I know is that this function uses regexp for replacing "<--KEYWORD--> key name of the array <--/KEYWORD-->"

The output of this csv in excel is as follows:

```
Client id   Client name Account manager 7.01    7.02    7.03    7.04    7.05
1234567     nameOne     manager1
1234568     nameTwo     manager2
```

My problem is with the ["messages_data"]=> array(5)
I want to put each int into a row after the corresponding account manager name.
Anybody can help?

Comment: a language tag is usually a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CVS file is filled through a "black box" php method... I want to put
>   each int into a row after the corresponding account manager name.
>   Anybody can help?

You may be asking a bit too much, wanting help with a "black box", but you can try extending the second line of the *csv file* to

```
<!--DATA1-->{{client_id}};{{name}};{{account_manager}};{{messages_data}}
```

Comment: You are right, help with a black box is too much. Days have passed and now i see it. Thank you.